# Regex in Textpad - Remove all text that is not enclosed inside quotes

Tags: regex, regex-negation, textpad

I am using Textpad to edit some text in which I need to do the following transformation,

Original Text

```
<ds:column name="REFRIGERATE" type="String" />
<ds:column name="REORDER_DRUG_ID" type="Double" />
```

Should become

```
REFRIGERATE            String
REORDER_DRUG_ID        Double
```

I need to extract everything that is in quotes and delete everything else.

```
"(.*?)" is not helping me.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following.

**Find :** `.+?((?<=")[^ ]+(?="))|"[^"]+$`

**Replace :** `\1\t`

I don't have `TextPad` installed but tested with `Notepad++` assuming both should be similar.